# How to make the page flipping animation like 20thingilearned.com

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I come across the google project http://www.20thingsilearned.com/ today and I found the canvas-based page flipping animation amazing.

Anyone knows the components to write a similar animation?

Comment: it might be best if you started by looking at the page source for that example...

Comment: I found the `canvas` element but don't know how the animation is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tutorial explaining the exact effect.

[20things_pageflip](http://html5rocks.com/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip/)

Answer (score 1):

jPageFlipper is a good solution for your project.

http://jpageflipper.codeplex.com/